# The PDF file is not saved in the Android 11 Download folder

Tags: android, file, pdf, download, document

Inside my software, a list of user information is generated offline as a PDF file. I tested this operation on Android 7 and 8 and everything was fine. But when I test on Android 11, the file is not generated. I was looking for a solution but I did not really find the complete source and training in this field.

I was able to create a PDF file via Intent, but inside another software, I saw that as soon as I clicked the save button, a folder with the program name was created in the Documents folder and the file was created inside.

This is the code I use to save the PDF file in the Download folder and it works for Android 7 and 8.

```
 public void savePdfFileToStorage(String pdfTitleHeader, String currentTime, PdfDocument pdfDocument, Context context) {
        String PdfDir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/Apple";
        File dir=new File(PdfDir);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdir();

        String fileName = pdfTitleHeader + "_" + todayDate() + "_" + convertToEnglishDigits(currentTime) + ".pdf";

        File file = new File(PdfDir,fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                Log.e(TAG, "savePdfFileToStorage: " + "file created" + file.getName() + "path: " + file.getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
            Log.e(TAG, "savePdfFileToStorage: pdf Wrote in file");
            Toast.makeText(context, "فایل PDF در پوشه Download/Apple حافظه داخلی ذخیره شد.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "فایل PDF ساخته نشد.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        pdfDocument.close();
    }
```

And I wrote these codes in the Manifest file.

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <application>
                    ...
                    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
                    ...
      </application>
```

Please advise where I should add the code to solve the storage problem in Android 11.

Comment: `if (!dir.exists())
            if(!dir.mkdir()) return;`

Comment: `String fileName = pdfTitleHeader + "_" + todayDate() + "_" + convertToEnglishDigits(currentTime) + ".pdf";` We have no idea what that would become. Please use a hard coded name.

Comment: You added code to ask the user to confirm the permissions in manifest?

Comment: If there is an exception then tell.

Comment: if (!dir.exists())             if(!dir.mkdir()) return;Do I need to write this code?

Comment: String fileName = pdfTitleHeader + "_" + todayDate() + "_" + convertToEnglishDigits(currentTime) + ".pdf"; We have no idea what that would become. Please use a hard coded name.   This code generates a similar name: allTransaction 20220202 10:15:23 .pdf

Comment: Yes, I added the Permissions request code in the manifest.

Comment: The program folder is created in Download but the PDF file is not created and gives this exception:         java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242750/discussion-between-reza-and-blackapps).

Comment: `Do I need to write this code?` No. I wrote it. You use it. Very strange question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > This code generates a similar name: allTransaction 20220202 10:15:23 .pdf

The `:` is a forbidden character in file names and paths.

Comment: But my files in Android 7 and 8 are made with the same structure of names.

Comment: What is it that you wanne say? And why dont we hear that that was the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much for telling me the rules for naming files. I deleted ":"

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code and was finally able to save the file in the Documents folder.

```
 public void savePdfFileToStorage(String pdfTitleHeader, String currentTime, PdfDocument pdfDocument, Context context) {
        File dir;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/Apple");
        else dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Apple");

      if (!dir.exists())
        if(!dir.mkdir())
           return;

        String fileName = pdfTitleHeader + "_" + todayDate() + "_" + convertToEnglishDigits(currentTime) + ".pdf";

        File file = new File(dir, fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                Log.e(TAG, "savePdfFileToStorage: " + "file created" + file.getName() + "path: " + file.getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
            Log.e(TAG, "savePdfFileToStorage: pdf Wrote in file");
            Toast.makeText(context, "فایل PDF در پوشه Download/Appleحافظه داخلی ذخیره شد.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "فایل PDF ساخته نشد.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        pdfDocument.close();
    }
```

Comment: Still you are not using the mkdirs() code i proposed. And why this answer? Its superflous.